# How to check kubelet configurations currently in use?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I basically want to find the hard eviction strategy that kubelet is currently using.
I checked the settings in the /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service file on my K8s node. In that the strategy I mentioned is as follows:
`--eviction-hard=nodefs.available<3Gi`

However, my pods seem to be evicted when the nodefs.available is <10% (default kubernetes settings) 
I have been unable to find a way a way to know the current parameters that are being used by kubernetes.

Comment: For posterity, note the /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh overwrites the evictionHard value in the config JSON, and will run after any userdata script you might provide. However, KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS such as set in bootstrap.sh sets in /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/30-kubelet-extra-args.conf take precedence over JSON config values.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is possible to dump the current kubelet configuration using `kubectl proxy` along with the `/api/v1/nodes/${TARGET_NODE_FOR_KUBELET}/proxy/configz` path.

For details, see [linked Kubernetes docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20181218105625/https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/) (⚠️ outdated documentation; now provided via Wayback Machine as historic reference material).

Answer (score 24):

You can use `kubectl` for that:

```
kubectl get --raw "/api/v1/nodes/<nodename>/proxy/configz" | jq
```

Just make sure you replace `<nodename>` with your node name. And if you don't have `jq` installed, leave out the  `| jq` part as that's only for formatting.

Comment: Thanks for including the example here, that worked very easily.

Comment: This saved me a lot of headache and stress! Worked perfectly. Thanks!